# Django form get_or_create

Tags: python, django, forms, models

how can I gat object ID on form save. The problem is, if object exists in database i just wana return object and save it into other form comparing value from form, else I wanna save new object in database. Below is my exmaple code, so if you can have a look.

## forms.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def NewOutgoingInvoice(request):

    template = "novi_izlazni_racun.html"
    user_pk = request.user.id
    org_name = OrganizationInfo.objects.filter(id=user_pk).values('name')[0]
    org_id = request.user.organization_id

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = InsertNewCustomer(request.POST)
        form2 = Outdrew(request.POST, request.user)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            a, created = OrganizationInfo.objects.get(oib__exact=cleaned_data['oib'])
            if created:
                b = form2.save(commit=False)
                b.user_id = request.user
                b.organization_id = org_id
                b.customer_id = created
                b.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/novi_izlazni_racuni/')
            else:
                a = form1.save()
                b = form2.save(commit=False)
                b.user_id = request.user
                b.organization_id = org_id
                b.customer_id = a
                b.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/novi_izlazni_racuni/')

    else:
        form1 = InsertNewCustomer()
        form2 = Outdrew()

    variables = RequestContext(request, dict(name=org_name, form1=form1, form2=form2))

    return render_to_response(template, variables)
```

Comment: I dont' understand the question. You can use `OrganizationInfo.objects.get_or_create` and it will either create the object return it from the DB. At the moment you are just using `get` which won't ever create a new instance. To get an object's id you simply use `object.id` or `object.pk`

Comment: Ok, let me refer. If object exists in database OIB. When form is submited if OIB match the OIB in database i just wanna save second form with OIB from database. If object dont exists save boh form.